# Pandas: how to compare columns of imported csv files to ensure they are the same?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have huge data split into 4 csv files. They are supposed to have the same columns and each file is the continuation of the previous.
I import the 4 CSV files in Pandas and before merging them I want to compare the columns for all 4 to identify any difference.

1. How do I do that with Pandas/Python?
2. Do I use merge or append? csv1 covers 2001 to 2004, csv2 covers 2005 to 2007 and so on, it's just split by time.

Comment: You should put what you tried.What do you mean by different.... Update your question please.

Comment: Do your csv files contain column names? If yes, do you know the correct column names which should be present?

Comment: Yes csv files contain column names, I want all files (csv2 onwards) to have the same columns as the first file (csv1)

Comment: The idea is to check if all column names in all files are the same

Answer (score 3):

When knowing your column names beforehand, you can explicitly pass them to the [`pd.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) via the `usecols` parameter. In case of a column name mismatch between your csv file and the predefined column names, an `ValueError` will be raised automatically.

To merge your csv-files you can use [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
# define your column names
column_names = ["Col A", "Col B", "Col C", "Col D"]

# setup file paths
base_path = os.path.join("E:/","Datasets","Dataset01") # adopted your example here
file_names = ["file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv", "file4.csv"]
abs_paths = [os.path.join(base_path, file_name)
             for file_name in file_names]

dfs = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(abs_path, usecols=columns_names) 
                 for abs_path in abs_paths])
```

In case you want to check if all columns are identical across your csv files, you can simply load only the header of the csv files while using `nrows=0`:

```
cols = [pd.read_csv(abs_path, nrows=0).columns
        for abs_path in abs_paths]

cols_identical = [all(cols[0] == colx) for colx in cols[1:]]
all_cols_same = all(cols_identical)
```

Comment: Thanks, how would it look like with the os.path.join, I usually use `import pandas
from os import path
df1 = pandas.read_csv(path.join("E:/","Datasets","Dataset01","csv1.csv"), error_bad_lines=False)` for one file. How do I get the os.path.join in your code, for all four csv files?

Comment: @MCGCode Modified the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have df1,df2 related with csv1,csv2

```
1. all(df1.columns == df2.columns)
2. pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Please check [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for detail.

Comment: Thanks. How to do it with all files at once? I now have 4 files, but some datasets have multiple files.

Comment: I mean how to compare the columns of all files at once

Comment: do you mean one function like f(df_columns) to check, while df_columns is one list of dataframe.columns? I am a little confused about all at once, as you know, you need to compare at least N times with N files :)

Comment: I give you an example of the logicalI have in mind which is not really correct in code but it is something like this: df1.columns == df2.columns == df3.columns == df4.columns or a some loop. I don't know.It's just That I needa code that would compare all the files, I should not need to compare each two files and move to the next 2 and so on.

Comment: For the algorithm you mention " should not need to compare each two files and move to the next 2 and so on", it may fail if columns of file1 == file2, file3==file4, but file1 != file3. I mean you have to compare at lease N times for N file, no matter compare each two files or compare file with a common standard.

Comment: how? a loop? what should the code be for df1, df2, df3, df4